# Solution to let employees modify information displayed on big television

Tags: windows, collaboration, todo

I work in an office environment and have two 42 inch TVs connected to my computer as additional monitors. I'm looking for some kind of software that will allow both myself and the other three employees in the office to edit the information displayed on the television from their own computers.

The information that needs to be displayed is just a to-do style list to keep track of what the priorities are in the office. Just text in a spreadsheet.

Two of the computers are running Windows 10 and two are running Windows 7.

A freeware solution would be preferable.

Comment: You said freeware, but if you are in an office, do you already have Microsoft Office? OneNote (Desktop) can support multiple people editing the same document and updating all views. (I think Word can, too).Are you willing to use cloud-based solutions which would involve the data leaving your office (DropBox, Office App Online, Google Apps, etc.)? Would plain text be good enough?

Comment: I was unaware you could use onenote and word for that. I have no problem using a cloud service, the main thing though is that it needs to be update-able by all four of us while the document is still open and displayed.
Thanks

Comment: `Just text in a spreadsheet` - there's your first mistake ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a **PowerPoint** presentation linked to an **Excel** spreadsheet that's shared among all four computers and writing a macro to auto-update the spreadsheet every time the PowerPoint looped.

It works, but I feel like there has to be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer; it will help others in future. You can also post a new question expalining what you don't like about your solution and asking for a btter one

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Trello](http://trello.com)? It's web-based project management application. It has the features you're looking for and some more. Everything is synced in real-time, so you will be able to see what changes your employees have made on the lists.
I used it when I managed a team of volunteers working on a farm, it was very useful.